# Mac OS File Sharing and Windows Client (Permission)

Tags: macos, file-permissions, file-sharing

I've a Mac Mini which I want to use as file server. I've the following directory structure that I want to share:

```
Public <-- shared (UserA and UserB readonly; Admin is owner)
 |- FolderA <-- (UserA is owner, read and write; UserB readonly)
 |- FolderB <-- (UserB is owner, read and write; UserA readonly)
```

I've I access the `public` share from a Mac client and `UserA` for examples creates a new subfolder in `FolderA` then `UserB` can read it.

But I've `UserB` for examples creates a new subfolder in `FolderB` from a PC client (Windows 10) then `UserA` cannot read it.

I've I take a look at the permissions it looks like that:

```
Public <-- shared (UserA and UserB readonly; Admin is owner)
 |- FolderA <-- (UserA is owner, read and write; UserB readonly)
     |- MacSubFolderA <-- (UserA is owner, read and write; UserB readonly)
 |- FolderB <-- (UserB is owner, read and write; UserA readonly)
     |- MacSubFolderB <-- (UserB is owner, read and write; UserA readonly)
     |- PCSubFolderB  <-- (UserB is owner, read and write; UserA has no access, WHY?)
```

I know the following workaround. I can apply the file permission of `FolderB` for all subfolders. But I don't want to do that by hand every time a PC client adds some files.

Comment: Does your problem sound similar to this one? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139736/how-to-automatically-apply-permissions-to-files-added-to-a-shared-folder In that case, maybe that's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set up [ACL inheritance permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4149) on the parent folders `FolderA` and `FolderB`.

First enable ACL permissions for SMB shares with the following command.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server AclsEnabled -bool YES
```

Second create an `UserGroup` that contains `UserA` and `UserB`.

Then set up inheritance permissions on the parent folders `FolderA` and `FolderB` with the following two commands.

```
sudo chmod -R +a "group:UserGroup:allow readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Public/FolderA
sudo chmod -R +a "group:UserGroup:allow readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Public/FolderB
```

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139762